# ScrollView isn't placed below ToolBar

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, android-constraintlayout

I faced with the following problem: `ScrollView` in my activity should be placed below `ToolBar`. Here's the layout of this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SongLyricsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lyrics_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when I run the app, I see this:

[image]

I don't understand, why it happens, as I position it below the toolbar, so, what's the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is happening because your scroll views height is `match_parent` and not `0dp` - so your scroll view will not respect your constraints and will spread all over your screen.**

Please notice that you are using `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` and the tool attribute will only affect the preview so you will see your layout in a different way from the preview.

In addition, you were missing some constraint - `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`

Now with that constraint, it should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lyrics_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem using a marginTop parameter (equals to toolbar height), like this:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/activity_show_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/transparent_background"
    >
```

This works for my app.

Answer (score 0):

you might try:

```
 <LinearLayout>
      vertical
      <RelativeLayout>
           <Toolbar>
               someID
               parent top
               parent left
           <Scrollview>
               below someID
               parent left
```